# Mobx React Reactivity with Hooks and Observer

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I've updated the app to use Mobx-react 6 along with Mobx state tree.
I'm not able to get the latest value inside the component when I use custom store hooks.

```
import { observer, MobXProviderContext, useObserver } from 'mobx-react';

function useStores() {
  return useContext(MobXProviderContext);
}

function useJob() {
  const { jobStore } = useStores();
  return useObserver(() => jobStore);
}



//USAGE

function ChildDocs(props) {
  const jobStore = useJob();
  const { validChildDocuments, setCurrentChildDoc, currentChildDoc, noneDocuments } = jobStore;
  
  //This won't update although the value in the store is null after re-mount. This shows the old value
  console.log('verificationDataStore=', currentChildDoc.verificationDataStore);

}
export default observer(ChildDocs);
```

Comment: Not quite understand why you need useObserver here `return useObserver(() => jobStore);`? It is usually used for jsx part of component. Did you try to remove it?

Comment: Nope Lemme remove it and see!

Comment: I initially did not use the observer HOC cos I though useObserver would take care of that.

Comment: Same issue even after removing useObserver(())

Comment: `useObserver` is basically alternative to observer HOC. It probably won't matter in this situation, it's just unneeded here. Next thing you want to check is that `currentChildDoc` and its properties are observable?

Comment: They're. They're part of a Mobx state tree. That'd make them observable by default.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with they way you pass stores to `<Provider>`? Everything else looks normal in your snippet.

Comment: I found the cause of my issue.
Using `import 'mobx-react/batchingForReactDom';` 
Solved it for me. 
Some warnings are not worth ignoring it seems :D

Comment: Can you vote to close this question